# in python's pexpect, how to cancel the print "TERM environment variable not set"

Tags: python, pexpect

I'm using python's pxssh, which inherits from pexpect and specializes in ssh.
my program writes commands to  a linux shell , and prints the output to a file.

Once in a while, I get a weird print:
"TERM environment variable not set."

How can I cancel it, or what does it mean?

I'll attach code if needed.

Comment: Perhaps by setting the TERM environment variable to something sensible?

Comment: Thanks! do you know what does "TERM environment variable" means , or how to do it with python..?

Comment: Use `os.environ['TERM'] = 'vt100'` Of course, you have to `import os` first.

Comment: @NogaLavi: is your google broken? Surely you can look up what the shell `TERM` enivronment variable and VT100 are yourelf?